# Has SELECT an INSERT clause?

Tags: sql-server, select

I know the form

```
Select * into new_table from old_table
```

statement. Bur recently I found 2 posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320621/copy-specific-table-data-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server/7320796#7320796) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cdnsoldevs/how-to-move-data-from-one-table-to-another) which use it like

```
SELECT * FROM NhlPlayer
INSERT INTO PlayerBackups
```

I find nothing in [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15), is that some new syntax or just a fault? I guess the later because

```
INSERT INTO PlayerBackups
SELECT * FROM NhlPlayer
```

would work fine.

Comment: Both are wrong syntax. I've -1 in the first and left a comment on the second.

Comment: Agreed with @gbn.  If you try a SELECT FROM then INSERT INTO, SQL Server takes that as two different entities.  In which the INSERT INTO is incorrect and missing pieces.

Comment: both posts have now been updated by their respective authors..  nice one @gbn

Comment: @Andrew Bickerton: Hurrah! I fixed something wrong on the interwebs http://xkcd.com/386/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both posts are **wrong** syntax.

I've -1 in the first from SO and left a comment on the second.

Create a table

```
SELECT * INTO PlayerBackups FROM NhlPlayer
```

Inserts to an existing table

```
INSERT PlayerBackups SELECT * FROM PlayerBackups
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
INTO new_table
FROM old_table
```

The above creates a new table based off of the source's table structure.  new_table, in this example, cannot exist or an error will be raised and the statement will not be committed.

```
INSERT INTO new_table_must_exist
SELECT *
FROM old_table
```

In this example, it copies data from old_table to new_table_must_exist.  Here new_table_must_exist must already exist, and the data mappings have to be compatible.